# extract response form axis.request | node js

Tags: node.js, axios

can you help me please, I need to extract some data from the axios  requests response, but I don't know how do it.

this is my code:

```
let result;

let config = {
    method: 'get',
    maxBodyLength: Infinity,
    url: urlToSend,
    headers: { 
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
    }
};

axios.request(config)
    .then((response) => {
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        result = response.data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });

console.log(result); //I NEED THE DATA HERE <-
```

The But the result is always: []

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `console.log(result)` is executed **before** the response is ready and **before** the code inside the `.then(...)` callback is executed. To make it wait until the response is ready and the value is assigned to the `let result;` variable you have to either:

1. Add `await` keyword at `axios.request(...)` like this, but note that top level `await` statements are not well supported across the platforms, but as long as you are in an async function you will be okay:

```js
await axios.request(config)
  .then((response) => {
  ...
```

2. or `console.log(...)` inside the `.then(...)` callback, or even better, just continue the `.then` chain:

```js
await axios.request(config)
  .then((response) => {
    return response.data
  })
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result)
  })
  .catch(err => {})
```

3. or probably the best and most readable thing to do is to just fully take advantage of the ES6 async/await syntax:

```js
async main() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.request(config);
    console.log(response.data)
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked for me, thanks a lot!